# Thread State - Runnable - even while thread is running

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a small program to check the state of my thread while running -

```
public class ClassExtendingThread extends Thread{

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i < 100;i++)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getState() + " - run method");
    }
}
```

But, the output shows it to be state to be Runnable. Shouldn't it be Running?

RUNNABLE - run method
   RUNNABLE - run method
   RUNNABLE - run method

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `Thread.State`? There's no `RUNNING` member of that enum, and the `RUNNABLE` description applies. *Always* read the documentation before asking a question here.

Comment: No, I didn't read. Point taken.

Answer (score 4):

The following are the possible states, according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html):

> NEW
>   A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
>   RUNNABLE
>   A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
>   BLOCKED
>   A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.
>   WAITING
>   A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.
>   TIMED_WAITING
>   A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.
>   TERMINATED
>   A thread that has exited is in this state.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct because Running is not a state in multithreading but runnable is a state in which thread  is executing in the Java virtual machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system such as processor.